# angularJS with spring MVC not displaying my page

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

hi guys i am new to angularjs and spring mvc. i have set up the basic application. but when i load it does not display anything. The console of the page says 404 not found. I have verified everything. But i do not know what am i doing wrong please help.

```
<!doctype html>
        <html ng-app="demoApp">
          <head>
              <script type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/services.css">
          </head>
          <body>
            <div>
                <div ng-view=""></div>  
            </div>
          </body>
          <script>
            var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp",[]);
            var controllers={};
            demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                    .when( '/view1',
                        {
                            controller:'simpleController',
                            templateUrl: '/views/view1.html'
                        })
                    .when('/view2',{
                        controller: 'simpleController',
                        templateUrl: '/views/view2.html'
                    })
                    .when('/getServices',
                        {
                            controller: 'servicesController',
                            templateUrl: 'views/services.html'
                        })
                    .when('/getCart',
                        {
                            controller: 'cartController',
                            templateUrl: 'views/shoppingCart.html'
                        })
                    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
            });
            demoApp.factory('simpleFactory',function(){
                var factory ={};
                var customers =[
                { name:'Taimoor Ali', city:'Paris' },
                {name:'Hassan Ali' , city:'Liverpool' }, 
                { name:'Mohsin Ali' , city:'Liverpool' }, 
                {name:'Shaheryar Ali' , city:'Helsinki'}
                ];
                var services = [
                    { name: 'Web Design', price: 200,active:true },
                    { name: 'JAVA', price: 500, active:false},
                    { name: 'PHP', price: 100, active:false },
                    { name: 'Testing', price: 400, active:false }
                ];
                var cart=[
                    {name: 'keyboard',price: 19.99,quantity: 1},
                    {name: 'Lipstick',price: 5.99,quantity: 3},
                    {name: 'Mouse',price: 14.99,quantity: 1}
                ];
                factory.getCustomers = function(){
                    return customers;
                };
                factory.getServices = function(){
                    return services;
                };
                factory.getCart = function(){
                    return cart;
                };
                return factory;
            });
            controllers.simpleController=function ($scope,simpleFactory){
                $scope.customers =[];
                init();
                function init(){
                    $scope.customers= simpleFactory.getCustomers();
                };
                $scope.addCustomer = function(){
                    $scope.customers.push({
                        name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                        city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                    });
                };
            }
            controllers.servicesController =  function($scope,simpleFactory){
                $scope.services = [];
                init();
                function init(){
                    $scope.services= simpleFactory.getServices();
                };
                $scope.toggleActive = function(s){
                    s.active = !s.active;
                };
                $scope.total =  function(){
                    var total=0;
                    angular.forEach($scope.services,function(s){
                        if(s.active){
                            total += s.price;
                        }
                    });
                    return total;
                };
            };
            controllers.cartController = function($scope,simpleFactory){
                $scope.cartItems=[];
                $scope.bill={};
                init();
                function init(){
                    $scope.cartItems = simpleFactory.getCart();
                };
                $scope.getCartTotal = function(){
                    var total=0;
                    angular.forEach($scope.cartItems,function(item){
                        total+=item.price*item.quantity;
                    });
                    return total;
                };
                function calculateDiscount(newValue, oldVelue,scope){
                    $scope.bill.discount = newValue > 100 ? 10 : 0 ;
                };
                $scope.getSubTotal= function(){
                    $scope.bill.subTotal = $scope.getCartTotal() - $scope.bill.discount;
                    return $scope.bill.subTotal;
                };
                $scope.removeItem = function(index){
                    $scope.cartItems.splice(index,1)
                }
                $scope.$watch($scope.getCartTotal,calculateDiscount);

            };
            demoApp.controller(controllers);
          </script>
        </html>
```

dispatcher-servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<! wont let me post bean links>

    <!-- Define some 'fake' controllers to redirect to view directly. -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" 
                         view-name="index"/>

    <!-- Static resources definitions to serve resources correctly .-->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="fonts/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/data/**" location="/data/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>


    <!-- View resolver to convert a view name into a view 'file'. -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <!--<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />-->
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>

    <!--Activation des annotations des controllers-->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>      
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.albeda.eecole.webapp.controller" />

    <!--     Active la prise en compte des properties  -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>texts</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>    

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:texts.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>index.html/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>WEB-INF/views/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

All my web pages are in `WEB-INF/views`.

Comment: actually the html pages can not be accessed in WEB-INF/..... by the view resolver is there anything that can be done about it i am really stuck plz help

Comment: Did u get any solutions of this issue?? I have a similar problem!!

Answer (score 0):

In spring MVC,The way to declare your home page is not through web.xml. But it is through your dispatcher servlet. So include the following line in your dispatcher-servlet.xml. This line should be included after your declaration of InternalResourceViewResolver bean class.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index"/>
```

This will map your page to  index.html by default.